# How to pass single Buttons into custom ConfirmationDialog

Tags: ios, swiftui, modal-dialog

I'm working on a custom ConfirmationDialog with icons, which works fine. The downside is that in the view modifier I can only access all buttons as one content container, so I can't put a divider between them, and also can't disable the overlay on button action (I have to do this in the calling closure).

Any ideas how I can pass the single buttons with their actions down into the modifier?

I was playing around with multiple TupleView inits but I'm not sure how to apply them to the modifier and View extension, let alone the button action.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var showConfirmationDialog = false
    @State private var showModifierDialog = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Show Dialog") { showConfirmationDialog = true }
            Button("Show ViewMod Dialog") {
                withAnimation {
                    showModifierDialog = true
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
        
        // standard confirmationDialog
        .confirmationDialog("Test", isPresented: $showConfirmationDialog) {
            Button { } label: {
                Label("Add completion", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
            }
            Button { } label: {
                Label("Add Note", systemImage: "note.text.badge.plus")
            }
            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {}
        }
        
        // custom confirmationDialog with Icons, Cancel added automatically
        .customConfirmDialog(isPresented: $showModifierDialog) {
            Button {
                // action
                showModifierDialog = false
            } label: {
                Label("Add completion", systemImage: "checkmark.circle")
            }
            Divider() // unfortunately this is still necessary
            Button {
                // action
                showModifierDialog = false
            } label: {
                Label("Add Note", systemImage: "note.text.badge.plus")
            }
        }
    }
}


// *** Custom ConfirmDialog Modifier and View extension

extension View {
    func customConfirmDialog<A: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder actions: @escaping () -> A) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(MyCustomModifier(isPresented: isPresented, actions: actions))
    }
}

struct MyCustomModifier<A>: ViewModifier where A: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @ViewBuilder let actions: () -> A
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            content
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                if isPresented {
                    Color.primary.opacity(0.2)
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .onTapGesture {
                                isPresented = false
                        }
                        .transition(.opacity)
                }
                
                if isPresented {
                    VStack {
                        GroupBox {
                            actions()
                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        }
                        
                        GroupBox {
                            Button("Cancel", role: .cancel) {
                                    isPresented = false
                            }
                            .bold()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                    .font(.title3)
                    .padding(8)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.easeInOut, value: isPresented)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is first of many tuples (you should support all of them to be compatible with ViewBuilder)

Tested with Xcode 14b3 / iOS 16

```
extension View {
    func customConfirmDialog<A: View, B: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, @ViewBuilder actions: @escaping () -> TupleView<(A, B)>) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(MyCustomModifier(isPresented: isPresented, actions: {
            let buttons = actions()
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                buttons.value.0
                Divider()
                buttons.value.1
            }
        }))
    }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: excellent! So I add an additional function for each Tuple count 3..4..5.. , right?

Comment: yep, as this is confirmation things there is probable a sense to stop on 5 or something.... 10 buttons for confirmation... sounds weird, don't you think? :)